# Memory leak with csv-parser & promises

Tags: node.js

i'm having trouble parsing a 800k lines CSV file line-by-line using the npm library 'csv-parser' and promises.

Here is what i am doing, simply pausing every row and resuming after the user has been upserted in the database.

At ~= 3000 users, more than 1gb of RAM is used and a memory heap usage exception appears.

```
const csv = require('csv-parser');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

function parseData() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const stream = fs.createReadStream(filePath)
      .pipe(csv(options))
      .on('data', row => {
        stream.pause();
        upsertUser(row)
          .then(user => {
            stream.resume();
          })
          .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            stream.resume();
          });
      })
      .on('error', () => reject())
      .on('end', () => resolve());
    return stream;
  });
```

the upsert function :

```
function upsertUser(row) {
  return user.find({
    where: {
      mail: row.emailAddress
    }
  });
```

edit : here is a picture of the node inspector :

[image: memoryheap]

Comment: If this is a line-by-line file, the [Readline API](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_event_line) might offer a better interface.  I think just listening to raw `data` events is overwhelming your parser by giving it too much data.  Can you provide a minimal dataset or some way to consistently reproduce the issue?

Comment: isn't the pause/resume functions supposed to handle that ? i'm gonna give a try to the readline API, thanks. I sadly can't really share much code or data for privacy reasons.

Comment: Well, I don't think it's that the pause/resume functions aren't doing their job, I think it's that you are eating too much data at once.  You pause when you get data, consume an arbitrary amount, unpause and let in an arbitrary amount more in over and over.  Try with readline, I think it may server you better.